# NetBeans on Ubuntu: Project's pom.xml file contains invalid xml content. Please fix the file before proceeding

Tags: maven, ubuntu, netbeans, pom.xml, cytoscape

My name is Angela and I'm developing a Cytoscape app.

I'm trying to access my maven project properties, but it returns me this error: "Project's pom.xml file contains invalid xml content. Please fix the file before proceeding."
When I build the jar file and execute it on Cytoscape I do not have any problem.

Can you help me to understand what is the error, please?

This is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>VF3Plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
    <artifactId>VF3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>VF3 OSGi Bundle</name>

    <properties>
        <bundle.symbolicName>org.cytoscape.vf3-bundle</bundle.symbolicName>
        <bundle.namespace>org.cytoscape.vf3</bundle.namespace>
        <cytoscape.api.version>3.7.2</cytoscape.api.version>

        <maven-bundle-plugin.version>2.5.3</maven-bundle-plugin.version>
        <osgi.api.version>4.2.0</osgi.api.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Links to the Cytoscape Maven repositories. -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cytoscape_snapshots</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <name>Cytoscape Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://nrnb-nexus.ucsd.edu/repository/cytoscape_snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>cytoscape_releases</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <name>Cytoscape Releases</name>
            <url>http://nrnb-nexus.ucsd.edu/repository/cytoscape_releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Activator>org.cytoscape.vf3menu.CyActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package/>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=!provided|test;groupId=!org.cytoscape</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
            <artifactId>swing-application-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cytoscape.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
            <artifactId>work-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cytoscape.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cytoscape.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cytoscape.api.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cytoscape</groupId>
            <artifactId>io-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>vf3jni</groupId>
            <artifactId>vf3jni.vf3jni</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-for-felix</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- To include a shell:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.gogo.shell</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
            -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                        <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                                        <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to="" />
                                    </pathconvert>
                                    <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="bundles">
                                        <path path="${plugins.jars}" />
                                        <mapper>
                                            <chainedmapper>
                                                <flattenmapper />
                                                <globmapper from="*" to="file:modules/*" casesensitive="no" />
                                            </chainedmapper>
                                        </mapper>
                                    </pathconvert>
                                    <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/config.properties">
                                        <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${bundles} file:modules/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                                        <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*" />
                                    </propertyfile>
                                    <copy file="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}" tofile="${project.build.directory}/felix.jar" />
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/felix.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>run-on-felix</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.gogo.shell:0.6.1 useless from Maven since stdin is swallowed -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="vm.args" value="" />
                            <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                                <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to="" />
                            </pathconvert>
                            <makeurl property="urls" separator=" ">
                                <path path="${plugins.jars}" />
                                <path location="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                            </makeurl>
                            <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties">
                                <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${urls}" />
                                <entry key="felix.auto.deploy.action" value="uninstall,install,update,start" />
                                <entry key="org.osgi.framework.storage" value="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}felix-cache" />
                                <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*" />
                            </propertyfile>
                            <makeurl property="run.properties.url" file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties" />
                            <java fork="true" jar="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}">
                                <sysproperty key="felix.config.properties" value="${run.properties.url}" />
                                <jvmarg line="${vm.args}" />
                            </java>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks reasonable to me after a quick glance.  The only thing that strikes me is your Export-Package tag, which is perfectly legal XML, but eclipse might not expect an empty tag there.  Just delete the empty tag (since it doesn't do anything anyways) and see if eclipse is happier.  Other than that, I would try stripping down your pom until eclipse stops complaining to determine what it doesn't like.

-- scooter